# JSQMessages: When I use photo messages my apps keeps crashing

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am building a chat app that is using `JSQMessagesViewController` to display images and `Firebase` as a backend.
The app is working without crashes when use text messages only, however when I add a photo message. The photo message is added to the collection view, however when I try to add a photo message, my app crashes on `finishSendingMessage()`.

Please help :)

[image: Function]

[image: Error]

[image: Console]

Comment: Why do you call `finishedRecivingMessageAnimated(true)` within your ` addMediaMessage()` and why don't you pull your function out so it is acceptable at the top level. That may help you here. Also just looking at your logic here I don't think you are actually saving the media item to firebase. You are only saving the `text` and `senderID` Your data is only being added to your local instance of messages.

Comment: Hey what was the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going through a similar issue and none of the above answers helped. My issue was:

-> media message added (worked fine)
-> text message added just after media message (app crashed)

I found that my problem lied in this piece of code in my cell for item at indexPath

```
    let message = messages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
    if message.senderId == senderId {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
```

I just commented out this code and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways for stopping the crash.The first one is to set this code in `viewdidload` 
**self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem = nil**
this code hides the image attachment button which is on the left side of the message view.
The other way is implement the method which library gives

```
 override func didPressAccessoryButton(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("imageTapped")
    }
```

also make sure to convert image in nsdata

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all first cross check user's senderId & senderName is not nil.

2) Also you can comment finishSendingMessage() line and you can use reloadMessage() which is avialable in JSQMessages, it will work.

3) As Daniel said you dont need to call finishedRecivingMessageAnimated(true)  within function.